# Why does the cloud chamber trails differ in length?

Tags: radiation

Why does the cloud chamber trails differ in length?
Also, why does the cloud chamber trails branch into Y-shape?

Comment: maybe you should link to a picture? Different lengths depend on the energy of the particles, as seeing the tracks is due to the energy loss by ionization.  Y shapes means interactions, i.e. the particle scatters strongly off an atom ( instead of just ionizing it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [cloud chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_chamber) is a detector which can make visual the track of particles. It is based on the fact that supersaturated vapors will condense around charge centers, i.e. ions, and that charged particles going through the chamber will generate  ions by [multiple scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering#Single_and_multiple_scattering). These make dots in the gas of the cloud chamber.

[[image: imagecloudchamber]]

The track trace depends on the charge, on the energy, on the mass, and one can from the thickness and the length of the path  deduce these parameters.  Delta rays are electrons which get a larger transfer of momentum in the mutiple scattering than the electrons that outline the track. Alphas because they have double charge make thicker tracks. The particles loose energy and finally stop, at least for energies coming from nuclear decays. Cosmic muons go through with a minimum ionization which gives an limit on their energy.

Comment: at this stage, after 100 plus years of examining tracks and trails, (and ignoring instrumental artifacts), are we able to identify and categorise every track we come across, or are there still occasional tracks that lead us to have to guess the event that caused them? Thanks

Comment: Yes for the low energy tracks, i.e. the ones that stop in the chamber because all their energy was transferred to the ionizing path. For through going tracks we may say whether they are muons or protons but the energy will not be known. In the more sophisticated bubble chambers the "guess" becomes a mathematical fit. New particles were found because the interaction would not fit with the known till then ones. This is old technology though. There are more sophisticated tracking devises with greater accuracies.

Comment: The techniques are cloud and bubble chambers are making a resurgence in the analysis of liquid noble-gas TPCs. With high spacial resolution and quantitative information on energy deposition in the working fluid there is a lot that can be learned, but it is still hard to differentiate between photon- and electron- initiated showers at times; or to sort those from $\pi^0$ decays in flight.

Comment: @dmckee I worked for more than ten years with the ALEPH TPC.  Started with prototype construction. A beautiful detector.